# Python strict string replacement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to replace rownum and rownum_ in "My num is rownum, your is rownum_" using `placeholderdict = {rownum:20, rownum_:25}.`

When I tried, it gets replaced like "`My num is 20, yours is 20_`" . Expected is "`My num is 20, yours is 25`"

Please share some tips.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: and did you mean this: `placeholderdict = {"rownum":20, "rownum_":25}`

Comment: Tip: use the `re` module to only perform substitutions between word boundaries

Comment: We can only tell you why your code is doing the wrong thing, if you show us your code.

Comment: You can use re.sub() with appropriate regex, (check for non matching groups or keep a rule to not have something else after your match (like _))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably replaced first “rownun“ and it replaced the “rownum_” Into 20_, just change the order it will fix your issue...

```
text = text.replace('rownum_', placeholderdict['rownum_'])
text = text.replace('rownum', placeholderdict['rownum'])
print(text)
>>> My num is 20, yours is 25
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
placeholderdict = {"rownum":20, "rownum_":25}
string = "My num is rownum, your is rownum_"
string = string.replace("rownum", str(placeholderdict["rownum"]), 1)
string = string.replace("rownum_", str(placeholderdict["rownum_"]))
print(string)
```

Add a `string.replace` and add `,1` to control the numbers of changing text. and add `str()`.

And your dictionary keys have to be a string because `rownum` and `rownum_` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Through Formatting, you can put it in {} that you want the value there.
If there is no name in {} then it will be in order, and you can also specify a value by name.

```
placeholderdict = {'rownum':20, 'rownum_':25}

print('My num is {rownum}, your is {rownum_}.'.format(rownum = placeholderdict.get('rownum'),
                                                      rownum_ = placeholderdict.get('rownum_')))
```

you can also save to value

```
text = 'My num is {rownum}, your is {rownum_}.'.format(rownum = placeholderdict.get('rownum'),
                                                      rownum_ = placeholderdict.get('rownum_'))
print(text)
```

Comment: add some explanation please.